# C++ anonymous union redeclaration error

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I want to create a struct that can be used to store 3D coordinates or a linear equation.
Here is the code:

```
struct myStruct {
    union {
        // coordinates (3d)
        struct {
            int x,y,z;
        };
        // linear equation (ax+b)
        struct {
            int a,b,x;
        };
    };
};
```

And I get the following error:

```
error: redeclaration of ‘int myStruct::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::x’
```

I'm on linux mint 18.04, g++ (5.4.0), compile with --std=c++11.

I understand the problem. But have few questions.

1. I saw something related working on windows, why?
2. What is the best way to implement it so it works well on both (linux/win)?

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't allow anonymous structures. You are relying on an extension anyway.

Comment: why do you want them to be anonymous? Btw your union has no members

Comment: @user463035818 I want to port a small c++ library that works on win, to make it work on linux and I came across this code (problem).

Comment: just give them names ;), they dont really matter after all.

Comment: @user463035818 :D Yeap I tried that and the problem was gone. Wondered if this can crash other things, and what are the best practices to avoid such situations in the future.

Comment: best practice is to write standard c++ and not rely on arcane extensions ;)

Comment: i dont know them by heart, but usually compilers offer a flag to disable any non-standard stuff while allowing only stricly conforming code

Comment: For GCC (and G++) use the flag: -pedantic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give them names. This should be fine:

```
struct myStruct {
    union {
        struct coordinates { int x,y,z; };
        struct linear_equation { int a,b,x; };
        coordinates coord;
        linear_equation lin_eq;
    };
};
```

I also allowed myself to add some members to the union. However, the two structs have members of same types and quantity, so imho entering the trouble of using a union is questionable.

Comment: But doesn't that mean you lose the ability to do: myStruct.x? I have a codebase that relies on this style on windows and it would be stressful to go through everyone's code and insert myStruct.coordinates/myStruct.linear_equation just to access the data members

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement the answer by [user463035818](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/user463035818). You can simplify your union a bit, by declaring the members directly, e.g.:

```
struct myStruct {
    union {
        // coordinates (3d)
        struct {
            int x,y,z;
        } coord;
        // linear equation (ax+b)
        struct {
            int a,b,x;
        } lin_eq;
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you, actually this is the exact workaround that I used :P